# Extending bootstrap in create react app

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-sass

I am tyring to extend boostrap classes in my sass file. I'm compiling my sass as in this [example](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc).

I have copied the boostrap files into my `/src` folder.

However, using this basic example:

```
@import "bootstrap/*";

.header{
    @extend .container;
    background-color:red;

}
```

I get the error:

**{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "C:/sites/mharrisweb-redux/src/sass/style.scss",
  "line": 1,
  "column": 1,
  "message": "File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/*.\nParent style sheet: C:/sites/mharrisweb-redux/src/sass/style.scss",
  "formatted": "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/*.\n       Parent style sheet: C:/sites/mharrisweb-redux/src/sass/style.scss\n        on line 1 of src/sass/style.scss\n>> @import \"bootstrap/*\";\n   ^\n"
}**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have this file structure:

```
src                
  bootstrap
  sass
    style.scss
```

You should use:

```
@import "../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

If you installed Bootstrap using package manager (npm or yarn), you could use:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```